# Undefined variable: class error in using bootstrap components in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

We are trying use bootstrap components for our fresh laravel project.

GitHub: https://github.com/appstract/laravel-bootstrap-components

we have following code in blade. but it doesn't work and have error.

blade codes:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('page-title','Welcome')

@section('content')
    @component('bootstrap::alert', ['type' => 'danger'])
        A simple alert of danger type
    @endcomponent
@stop
```

error:

> **ErrorException** (E_ERROR)  Undefined variable: class (View:
>   B:\xampp\htdocs\me2we\resources\views\vendor\bootstrap\alert.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   B:\xampp\htdocs\me2we\resources\views\vendor\bootstrap\alert.blade.php)

what we have to do to fix it?

Comment: No idea, your error is not in this code. Show your full alert.blade.php.

Comment: Where did you use the $class variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

It seems [alert.blade.php](https://github.com/appstract/laravel-bootstrap-components/blob/master/resources/views/alert.blade.php) contains the following snippet:

```
{{ $class or '' }}
```

The latest version of Laravel no longer supports `or` between curly brackets in blade. These have been replaced by [PHP 7's null coalesce operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

So it should now be like this:

```
{{ $class ?? '' }}
```

More info: https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator